# What is the meaning of the sentence? I could not understand how the "know" word is used

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Know the Village of Tree does not fear them!

Answer (score 1):

It's a request or a command to the reader or listener that they should know what the sentence is proclaiming. Similar to, but stronger than "you should know that.."